# Permanently change xkb keybindings?

Tags: x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a custom keyboard layout located in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. Every time an update happens, this file is updated to the standard keyboard layout. Is there either a way to change this permanently, or a way to change this in userspace away from distro-level config?

If there is a better way to approach custom keyboard layouts, please let me know. As far as I am aware, the best way to approach this is with xkb symbols files, and there is not much documentaion for these.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? Debian-based distributions (using `dpkg`) have a concept of `divert` which allow you to tell them not to override a custom file of yours...

Comment: That's why you don't modify existing layouts, but instead you make your own layout based on an existing layout, copying and modifying files as necessary.

Comment: @filbranden: debian has bitten me with this before, so it could be debian/ubuntu.

Comment: @dirkt: an explanation for someone who isn't familiar with where custom layouts are stored or how they are loaded would be appreciated. I've seen this advice before but never a "for dummies" guide.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: There's no for dummies guide because the whole thing is a bit complex, and depending on what you want to do you may need to copy and modify quite a few files. The best introduction to XKB I know is the [Unreliable guide to XKB configuration](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/xkb.pdf) by Doug Palmer.

Answer (score 3):

Make a directory tree under `/home/<user>/` which has the same structure as `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`.  In other words:

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── compat
├── geometry
├── keycodes
├── rules
├── symbols
└── types
```

So put the relevant files in `compat`, `symbols`, etc.  You obviously don’t need to make empty directories, just the directories for the files that you need.

Then consider renaming your symbols file to something different than `us`.  There might be a way to disambiguate your own `us` symbols file from the one under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/`, but it is easier to just pick a new name which doesn’t appear in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.  `mine` will do fine.

Let’s say that you put your custom Xkb directory at `/home/<user>/my-xkb` and that your custom symbols file is named `mine`.

If you use `setxkbmap(1)` to set your layout you simply need to change it to print its output and pipe it to `xkbcomp(1)`.  So if this is your `setxkbmap` invocation:

```
setxkbmap mine
```

You will need to change it to this:

```
setxkbmap mine -print |
    xkbcomp -I"/home/<user>/my-xkb" - "$DISPLAY"
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than need be, since the person asking clearly has write permissions in the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols directory. Without those write permissions (which is a common use-case!), this is a great answer!

Comment: @AkselBergfeldt Personally I don’t care if I have write permissions in these weird system directories. I want all of my customizations to live in my home directory. I don’t want state to accumulate from ad hoc copying into `/usr/share/` or wherever else.

Comment: But the above is moot for me since I live under some kind of Wayland regime on 22.04 now (obviously I wasn’t in 2019). So now I have to copy into `/usr/share` because Wayland doesn’t like xkbcomp.

Comment: Those are good points! A fair amount of people will stay in the X world for another couple of years (decades?) though, so this will surely be of use a while longer.

Answer (score 1):

Guildenstern's solution does not work with my system so I had to look for a different solution. I did the following:

1. I created a customised keybinding.
2. I named it exactly like the standard keybinding I selected in *System Settings* (I use Manjaro).
3. I saved it in my home directory.
4. I created a bash-script named `10-restxkbmap.sh` in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/` with the following contens:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   diff -q /home/neo/.config/neo/xkb/symbols/us /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us >/dev/null
   if [ $? -eq 1 ]
   then
     sudo cp /home/neo/.config/neo/xkb/symbols/us /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
   fi
   ```
5. This script is run from inside `~/.xinitrc` replacing the standard keybinding with my customised version whenever needed and (best of all) before the login prompt is displayed so my binding is active when I have to enter the password.

Comment: You are right. I corrected the shebang. Thanks for pointing out the potential error and correcting the formating.

Comment: My answer might not have worked because Wayland (or XWayland or whatever it is) doesn’t like xbkcomp. So as a temporary measure (with my current setup) I have had to resort to copying the files into `/usr/share`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to make a new symbols file with your custom layout. Copy the us symbols file, make your edits in the default layout and save it as e. g. milquetoast in the same directory. You can then simply load these symbols with

```
setxkbmap milquetoast
```

As long as there is no new language called milquetoast suddenly showing up, this file is never going to be overwritten with updates.